# Movie about underground monster trying to kill kids

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a movie that I saw 7-8 years ago about some kids slipping through the gutter or something. They're underground and there are rooms or some temple or something and a type of monster that's trying to kill the kids/teenagers. The monster is slow moving and hairy.

I can't find that movie or whatever it was, and by the looks of it, it was made in the 80s or 90s.

Comment: Well was it a movie or not?

Comment: yeah it was a movie but just don't remember the name of the movie or the cast. :(

Comment: What did the monster look like?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds kinda like the plot of It (Stephen King). Which did air as a miniseries in 1990

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_%281990_film%29

Comment: nope.i also had a feeling that it would be related to SK but i checked his every movie and novels but couldn't find what i was looking for. the plot of IT is similar but there wasn't a clown. it was some kind of slow walking monster

Answer (score 3):

How about "Little Monsters" (1989)?

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097758/?ref_=nm_knf_i4

Brian Stevenson falls into a hole under his bed and finds himself in a world populated by monsters, including the large (and hairy) Snik, a monster who hates children and bullies even the other monsters. The monster world contains passages which lead back to the human world, including ones that come out in gutters, closets, etc.

Check out the [article on  Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Monsters) for a full plot summary.

Comment: This sounds like the right answer to me. I added a slightly fuller summary and a Wikipedia link.

Comment: I really want to see his response if this is correct or not.

Comment: unfortunately, sometimes people post a question and never come back. Or at least, never say whether or not someone is right. Story/Movie Identification questions are the worst at that. It's frustrating, but something we have to live with.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Pan's Labyrinth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%27s_Labyrinth) ?  The fit:

- 2006 release date is compatible (but the fact it preferred make-up and animatronics to CGI give it an older look).
- The Labyrinth is accessed through a hole in the floor (might be remembered as a "gutter").
- One monster is the "Pale Man, a child-eating monster..."
- Mostly it's just Ofelia goes into the labyrinth, but later she takes her brother too.

It doesn't have a notably hairy/slow monster though as far as I remember (although it does have a [faun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLpPDAQ0Z3s), and the [Pale Man can be outrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSsfuEG4GMA), just!).

Answer (score 1):

Try 'The Cellar'  From 1989.  I found it somewhere online years ago.  basically the monster is this overgrown bear/wolf thing with huge snaggle teeth and it has tunnels that connect from the pond outside the house to the cellar of the house.  It terrorizes the kids who live in the house.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Don't Look Under the Bed"?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Look_Under_the_Bed

Comment: nope. the plot is going or falling from a gutter or hole to an underground place where there are rooms and stuff very old and the kids/teenagers find out there is a monster, a big hairy type thing.